# How to learn language to read math text?

Tags: soft-question, advice

I recently discover new mathematical wealth in non-English texts. Sadly, the two language that I speak are not German, Russian, Chinese, French, or languages that belong to the world leading math research nations.

I want to learn these **specifically for mathematics with NO emphasis on speaking, listening, basically NO conversation in general, just math** - which would make the process more tedious.

**What is the best way to achieve this goal?** Would using a dictionary to read an article a good way to learn? But every language has some structure behind it and it may be impossible to figure out what certain things mean without that knowledge.

Comment: What mathematics do you want to learn? And also why are the books of mathematics in your languages not sufficient?

Comment: Google translate will probably get you pretty far

Comment: 'Russian for the Mathematician' by Sydney Gould has been on my reading list for a while.  It's fairly short and may be what you're looking for, or at least be a good starting point.

Comment: I guess the languages of most articles are pretty similar when the actual math part starts. So you only need the correct vocabulary. Sometimes they are similar. Some are even the literal translations of the original words. Sometimes they are totally different. For example field is "Körper" in german, which has no resemblance. On other hand to map / mapping is "abbilden" / "Abbildung" in German, which have the same literal meaning.

Comment: @DMcMor Thank you. That seems to be a useful book.

Comment: @mdave16 I recently ran into an incident where the only comprehensive resource comes from a book in German. And even though it is already in its 6th edition, I find no translation.

Comment: You can begin by French: it is the language whose vocabulary is the closest to English, a fact that is not enough underlined, and whose structure is very analytical (as is German, but in a different way). Some authors of the first part of the 20th century are especially clear like Borel and Lebesgue...

Answer (score 4):

When I was a junior math major at a small midwestern (US) liberal
arts college, my instructor chose a book in French for the text.
He brushed away complaints that none of us knew French by saying
that the math would be so hard that we'd hardly notice the inconvenience
of learning French. He was correct on both counts.

That is my introduction to agreeing with @JeanMarie that you might
do well to start with French. There are a lot of cognate words and French
mathematicians seem to specialize in simple, elegant presentations.
(With French, it does help to have someone around who knows the
pronunciation, because it makes reading easier. The rules are fairly simple,
and almost correct is good enough.)

Learning to read mathematics in any foreign language is made simpler
by several almost-facts: almost everything is in the present tense and the
third person, and
you can begin by choosing books and articles on familiar topics so that you
almost know what the words amongst the equations must mean.

One recommendation as you begin is that it may help to start with
books written by people who were writing in what was to them a
foreign language. Copy editors will have fixed the mistakes and the
vocabulary will tend to be utilitarian. A Pole writing French, a Russian writing German,
etc. Specifically, Casimir Kuratowski's *Topologie* and A. N. Kolmogorov's
foundational tract on probability theory in German.

Another recommendation is to be absolutely fearless. No one will know about the initial mistakes
you make. When writing my PhD thesis I needed to use a Russian journal
article during the summer when all the Russian speakers I knew were on vacation.
I knew no Russian, not even the alphabet. It took me almost half an hour
to look up the first word, but then I (almost) knew the alphabet. I encountered a
couple of places where it mattered whether the text was saying 'A of B' or 'B of A',
but a quick look at a grammar text took care of that. Fortunately, the 
article was only 3.5 pages long, mostly equations. Three days, and I got what I needed.

I have no recommendations on getting started with Chinese.

Comment: Which book what is?

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice! I will look over Kolmogorov's work in German. And that was indeed an interesting story.

Comment: I think it's in a Chelsea edition.